# How to Obtain Connection string for mysql with ubuntu server?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect to mysql database from C#, but I have no idea how to get the connecttion string, since ubuntu is not like mssql has a visual UI. I have install phpmyadmin on ubuntu server already

Comment: take a look here on how to connect to different types of databases hopefully this will help [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: Thank You for your both answers

Comment: But I'm not sure about the Server=myServerAddress. Does it mean my IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should looks like this

```
var str="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword";

var connection = new MySqlConnection(str);
```

`myServerAddress` is the Ip of your server
`Database` is the name of your Databas
`Uid` is the username of the user that you want to use to authenticate to the database

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But i'm not sure what should I put in the "Server=myserveraddress"

Comment: the ip of your server e.g. 172.12.7.xxx

Comment: @Rain it would be the server address, if its a local server this would be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. Otherwise its the IP of the host server.

Comment: One more question, when I was searching youtube video online, I see some people put in the port 3306 too, what is that for?

Comment: The port 3306 is the default MySql port, generally you should specify that, it depends on your server

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. Because my server is ubuntu server and it is localhost on the ubuntu server.  I went on my phpmyadmin it says "localhost - yysq(the database name)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66038/discussion-between-rain-and-faby).